# How to find percentage within a group in sql that has inner join as subquery?

Tags: mysql, rdbms

I have 3 tables like this

```
create table Users (id serial primary key, country varchar(100) not null);

create table tweets(id serial primary key, user_id int, text varchar(100) not null, CONSTRAINT FK_TWEETSUSERS FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES Users(id));

create table Logins(user_id int, client varchar(100),  CONSTRAINT FK_LOGIN_USERS FOREIGN KEY (user_id)
    REFERENCES Users(id));
                                                                                 
insert into Users
values
(1,'Japan'),
(2, 'Moroco'),
(3,'Japan'),
(4,'India'),
(5,'India'),
(6,'Japan'),
(7,'Moroco'),
(8,'China');
                     
insert into tweets
values
(733,1,'I love #food'),
(734,1,'I love food'),
(735,2,'I love #food'),
(736,5,'I love food'),
(737,6,'I love #food'),
(738,3,'I love #food'),
(739,8,'I love #food');      
                     
insert into Logins
values
(1,'mobile-ios'),
(2,'mobile-ios'),
(3,'mobile-ios'),
(4,'web'),
(8,'mobile-ios');
```

I need to find percentage of users from each country whose users have used '#food' in their tweets and the other condition is that user should have logged in using 'mobile' device

I have written the following query so far -

```
select t.country, count(t.country) as tweet_users
from 
(select Mobile_User_Tweets.user_id, U.country from Users as U
inner join
(select distinct user_id from tweets 
where text like '%#food%' 
and user_id in (select distinct user_id 
                                from Logins 
                               where client like '%mobile-%')) as Mobile_User_Tweets
on U.id = Mobile_User_Tweets.user_id) as t
group by t.country ;
```

This gives the number of users from a country that have user #food in their tweets

Result below -

```
country tweet_users
Japan   2
Moroco  1
China   1
```

I want the following result -

```
 country    tweet_users

Japan   66.67      -------------> (2 out of 3 users from Japan) 

Moroco  50         -------------> (1 out of 2 users from Moroco)

China   100        -------------> (1 out of 1 user from China)
```

I tried number of different queries to find the percentage but haven't been able to get the result?

Can some one help me with this?

Comment: Please tag only a single RDBMS... not multiple.

Comment: And for a fast response I recommend providing your sample data as DDL+DML i.e. create temp table insert into temp table.

Comment: @DaleK I updated the question with the create, insert queries. Hope that helps

Comment: I don't understand what the PK on the logins table is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to achieve the results you want is to check in a derived table whether a user has made any tweets about `#food`; then you can `LEFT JOIN` that table to `Users` and `Logins` to determine the average number of users from each country that have logged in from mobile and tweeted about food:

```sql
SELECT u.country,
       AVG(COALESCE(t.tfood, 0) AND COALESCE(l.client, '') LIKE '%mobile-%') * 100 AS tweet_users
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Logins l ON l.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, MAX(text LIKE '%#food%') AS tfood
  FROM tweets
  GROUP BY user_id
) t ON t.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.country
```

Output:

```
country     tweet_users
China       100.0000
India       0.0000
Japan       66.6667
Moroco      50.0000
```

If you don't want countries with no users that meet the criteria, just add `HAVING tweet_users > 0` to the end:

```sql
SELECT u.country,
       AVG(COALESCE(t.tfood, 0) AND COALESCE(l.client, '') LIKE '%mobile-%') * 100 AS tweet_users
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN Logins l ON l.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, MAX(text LIKE '%#food%') AS tfood
  FROM tweets
  GROUP BY user_id
) t ON t.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.country
HAVING tweet_users > 0
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=e89bfdce2c37b9ac94ae6d20b46c3b00)

Note this code takes advantage of the fact that in a numeric context, MySQL treats boolean expressions as 1 (true) or 0 (false).

Note that if a user might have multiple entries in the `Logins` table, you need to make a derived table from that too:

```sql
SELECT u.country,
       AVG(COALESCE(t.tfood, 0) AND COALESCE(l.mclient, 0)) * 100 AS tweet_users
FROM Users u
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, MAX(client LIKE '%mobile-%') AS mclient
  FROM Logins
  GROUP BY user_id
) l ON l.user_id = u.id
LEFT JOIN (
  SELECT user_id, MAX(text LIKE '%#food%') AS tfood
  FROM tweets
  GROUP BY user_id
) t ON t.user_id = u.id
GROUP BY u.country
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.7&fiddle=1adfa851610537d237b263bb2a50bbc0)

Comment: Thanks @Nick. This sure does help! I am trying to understand the query.. Can you please help me understand why the approach that I am using is not a good one as opposed to using LEFT join?

Comment: @ZankhanaRana I'm using a `LEFT JOIN` because it will also give me a row (with `NULL` values) for every user regardless of whether they meet either the "tweet contains #food" or "client contains mobile" constraints. I can then simply take the average of my condition (which is that they meet both constraints) to determine what percentage of users do meet the constraints.

Comment: @ZankhanaRana Please note that the original query doesn't deal with the case where a user might have multiple entries in `Logins`. If that is the case, you need to modify the query to make a derived table from `Logins` in the same way as I did with `tweets`. Please see my edit for how to do that.

Comment: Oh okay, this makes sense. And yes, the Logins table can have multiple entries for a user. Thank you for catching that.

Comment: @ZankhanaRana no worries - I should have thought of it originally!